# ERROR An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

Deleting Object from s3 cause Access Denied Error

my s3 IAM

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'storages',
]

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
```

django code

```
def UpdateCompanyView(request):
    user = request.user
    company = user.company
    old_logo = company.logo
    if old_logo and 'logo' in serializer.validated_data and data_logo is not None:
        old_logo.delete()
    #old_logo.delete(save=False)#I've tried this also
```

other all actions working put, add, but deleting occurring this error

Comment: How do you know that it is this line of code which causes this error ? Can you put the error trace ?

Comment: because the error is causing only in deleting, if I remove .delete() method it works, and same check the was error it also Permission denied while deleting object

Comment: What is the bucket policy?

Comment: when the Iam policy set there is not need bucket policy

Comment: That is **incorrect**. Both IAM policies & S3 bucket policies go hand in hand, with the ultimate authorization being the least-privilege union of all the permissions. Do you have a bucket policy set?

Comment: here is bucket policy

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cardx",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cardx/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you're provided is okey, I think the problem is with your IAM user I'll suggest you create a new user with new keys. and add this policy to your bucket

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3_POLICY",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS_USER_ID:user/USER_NAME"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've created a new user and add bucket policy it work for me, Thank you.